# Draggable Text behind Responsive Object - WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, text, drag

i wanna make something likes this but i'm using WordPress currently, i tried to make the orange object using image, but it makes the text behind it can't be dragged so some script won't work (being covered by the image). so is there any possibilities to make the text in yellow dashed area draggable? is it delete the image and using css object instead or there's any other better way? thank, here's the illustration..
[illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/grbxt.jpg)

Comment: Where is the code that you tried?

Comment: @DragonBorn ouhh, sorry berfore, I'm currently using wordpress and visual composer..